# Redshift - psycopg2.DataError when passing timestamp as a variable

Tags: python-3.x, variables, amazon-redshift

I have a python script that takes in 3 arguments as part of a Python function. Given below is the function:

```
def func(name,start_date,end_date):
    db_details
    db_cursor = con.cursor()   
    db_cursor.execute("""select '%s' as name,count (*)
from datamart 
where sale_date between '%s' and '%s'"""), 
(name,start_date,end_date)
```

Get the below error when I try to execute the above:

```
psycopg2.DataError
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "%s"
```

Could anyone advice on where I am going wrong in the above code. I am connecting to a Redshift DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, as it won't add single-quotes on it's own while formatting the string.

```
"""select '{arg_1}' as name,count (*) from datamart  where sale_date between '{date_1}' and '{date_2}'""".format(arg1=arg1,date_1=date_1_str,date_2=date_2_str)
```